# Question on redefinition of an expectation

Tags: measure-theory

There is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathrm{B},P)$. Let $Y$ be a positive random variable with $E(Y)=1$. Define $P^*(A) = \int_A Y\,dP.$ Show that

a. $E^*(X)=E(XY)$ for any random variable $X\geq 0$.

b. For any $X\geq 0$ that $$ E^*(X|Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) = \frac{E(XY|Z_1,\cdots,Z_n)}{E(Y|Z_1,\cdots,Z_n)} $$ for any random variables $Z_1,\cdots,Z_n$.

My attempt:

a. $E^*(X)=\int_\Omega X\,dP^* = \int_\Omega X \int_{dw}Y\,dP = \int_\Omega XY\,P(dw)$.

$E(XY)=\int_\Omega XY\,P(dw)$.

This proves part a. My question: Why do we require $X$ to be non-negative? Please provide any hints if my approach has some flaws in it.

b. I was attempting to solve this using [Question on conditional expectation like chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024823/question-on-conditional-expectation-like-chain-rule), but alas, this approach seems to be wrong.

So, any hints to solve this problem will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Seems just flawed. For instance, what does $dw$ even mean? Try the following. Consider $\mathscr{H}_+$ the set of random variables $X \geq 0$ for which $\mathbf{E}^*(X) = \mathbf{E}(XY).$ Then $\mathscr{H}_+$ contains all indicator functions of events (by definition), is a closed under addition, positive-scalars multiplication and closed under monotone limits. Hence, $\mathscr{H}_+$ contains all non-negative random variables (for we recall if $X$ is such a random variable, then $X$ equals, a.s., a monotone limit of *simple* positive r.v.). Now, in regards as to *why* $X$ has to be non-negative, it is just for the expectations to exist. You could also ask $X$ to be bounded.

b. Consider now the sigma algebra $\mathscr{X}$ generated by $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n.$ By definition, $\mathbf{E}^*(X \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)$ is any random variable, measurable with respect to $\mathscr{X},$ for which the following relation holds: if $\mathrm{E} \in \mathscr{X}$ then $$\int\limits_{\mathrm{E}} \mathbf{E}^*(X \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) d\mathbf{P}^* = \int\limits_{\mathrm{E}} X d\mathbf{P}^*.$$
However, by virtue of a., we know that the right hand side above equals $\int\limits_\mathrm{E} XY d\mathbf{P}$ which, in turn, equals $$\int\limits_\mathrm{E} \mathbf{E}(XY \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) d\mathbf{P} = \int\limits_\mathrm{E} \dfrac{\mathbf{E}(XY \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)}{\mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)} \mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) d\mathbf{P}.$$
Apply the result of a. to the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{X}, \mathbf{P})$ using  $\mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)$ in lieu of $Y$ (recall $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)) = \mathbf{E}(Y)=1$ and $\mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) \geq 0$) to get $$\int\limits_{\mathrm{E}} \mathbf{E}^*(X \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) d\mathbf{P}^* = \int\limits_\mathrm{E} \dfrac{\mathbf{E}(XY \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)}{\mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)} d\mathbf{P}^{**},$$ where $\mathbf{P}^{**}$ is the probability measure on $\mathscr{X}$ such that $\mathbf{P}^{**}(\mathrm{A}) = \int\limits_\mathrm{A} \mathbf{E}(Y \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n) d\mathbf{P}$; by definition of conditional expectation, $\mathbf{P}^{**}(\mathrm{A})=\mathbf{P}^*(\mathrm{A})$ for all $\mathrm{A} \in \mathscr{X},$ that is $\mathbf{P}^{**} = \mathbf{P}^*.$ This substantiates b. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks for such an elegant proof idea! There is a typo at the end I believe. It should be $\mathbf{P}^{**}(\mathrm{A})=\mathbf{P^*}(\mathrm{A})$ right?

Comment: Yes. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025024/question-on-independence-of-conditional-expectation as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, modify my argument here from a.

Comment: How about the approach mentioned in the details over there?

Comment: I am actually not sure what you mean. I am sure, however, that the argument of a. here can be modified to prove that exercise.